# google apps engine authentification Flex

Tags: android, apache-flex

I successfully did an application that uses Flex as a client as GAE as a backend.
I would now like to public my application to a mobile device (galaxy tab) and still use my GAE application.
What would be the best solution to authentificate to the google account ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google requires user to visit it's own web page and set some cookies there so the only way is to show the browser (internal or system) window with Google's UI.

When user successfully enters he is redirected to the URL you provide. When that URL is loaded you can grab his e-mail from the browser via JavaScript and treat user as authenticated.